# Problem when sending a long string through serial Com port (python to arduino)

Tags: python, arduino, serial-communication

I am trying to send an array of strings as a big string separated with characters(#) to arduino through serial.write. So that once the string in arduino i can separated it again into a string array. However, when i run this code, the print(finalData) part prints nothing. what am i doing wrong?

python code:

```
array = ["the first", "second","third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth"]

serialArduino = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600,timeout=1, write_timeout = 1)

data = ""
for i in range(len(array)):
    data += array[i]
    data +='#'
data += '\n'    

print(data)

serialArduino.write(data.encode('utf-8'))

finalData = serialArduino.readline().decode('ASCII')
print(finalData)
```

arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(1);
}
void loop() {
  
  
  if(Serial.available()>0){
    String data = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');   
    Serial.print(data);
  }
}
```

I wanna add that i am using vscode for the python end and showcasing any Serial prints from arduino in the python terminal using readline().

I have been debugging this for a while and it seems that the serial.write function is not sending any data as in my arduino code i am unable to detect any incoming data greater than 0 using serial.avaiable()

Comment: Read how [readline()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) works, what if you change `Serial.print(data);` to `Serial.println(data);`?

Comment: nothing changes. I have been debugging for a while and the problem is that there is no communication between the two codes. Even tho i have serial.write line with encoding, the Serial.available in the arduino code nevers goes above 0. I dont know this is happening

Comment: Are you the COM3 is the correct port? And do you quit the Arduino IDE before using your python code?

Comment: i dont close the Arduino IDE, is it a necessary step?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the timeout to 1 millisecond (!!) This is probably not long enough. I'm not sure you need a timeout at all here.

Comment: Any suggestions for the timeout value? i removed both from arduino and python but it got stuck and it doesnt print the line still

Comment: Can you verify if the data is getting to the arduino at all? Try flashing an LED in the arduino code if it successfully reads anything

Comment: i Tried adding a LED to turn on when sending the code from python but it doesnt. it seems that the problem is that it is not even reading it